# startActivity is undefined when running Nativescript-Vue app not via Playground

Tags: android, vue.js, nativescript

I created a very small app, and for Android it show go into immersive mode upon load of the first page. The problem I have is that `app.android.startActivity` is undefined and so I can't get the Decor Window to change the System UI Visibility. If I inspect via Chrome's Devtools I can easily access the StartActivity and when I try the same code in the playground it works perfectly.

```
<template>
 <Page
  class="page page__start"
  actionBarHidden="true"
  backgroundSpanUnderStatusBar="true"
  @loaded="pageLoaded"
>
 <StackLayout>
   <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="column">
   </FlexboxLayout>
 </StackLayout>
 </Page>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
 methods: {
  pageLoaded: (args) => {
    const app = require('application');
    const platform = require('platform');
    const View = android.view.View;

    if (app.android && platform.device.sdkVersion >= '21') {
      const window = app.startActivity.getWindow();
      const decorView = window.getDecorView();
      decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
    }
  }
 }
};
```

Update: Here is the package.json, I don't think it is a dependency issue, due to application and platform shouldn't be dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@teammaestro/nativescript-svg": "^1.0.1",
  "ajv": "^6.5.1",
  "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
  "nativescript-vue": "^1.3.1",
  "tns-core-modules": "~3.4.1",
  "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
  "vuex": "^3.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
  "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
  "nativescript-vue-externals": "^0.2.0",
  "nativescript-vue-loader": "^0.1.5",
  "nativescript-vue-target": "^0.1.0",
  "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^1.3.1",
  "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
  "ns-vue-loader": "^0.1.2",
  "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
  "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
  "webpack": "^3.11.0",
  "webpack-synchronizable-shell-plugin": "0.0.7",
  "winston-color": "^1.0.0"
}
```

Here a link to the **working** playground: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=m1qdiD

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

If it works on playground. It can be a dependency issue. Have you installed all the plugins using npm? It would be great if you can add the dependency versions from package.json. There might be a potential error in here: 
`const app = require('application');
const platform = require('platform');` 
Also, check if you have  tag.  I recommend sharing your NativeScript-Vue playground URL.

Comment: Updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and got it working just by calling the `startActivity` from `app.android.startActivity` insted of `app.startActivity`.